# Running a background service which never stops (or always restarts)

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm building an Android Wear service which runs in the background and logs device data every three minutes. For this logging, I am using a `Handler`, which records the values and then has an interval of three minutes. This will be used to monitor user behaviour for one month, and as such it should not randomly stop.

I have also used `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` in my manifest and this successfully runs the application whenever the watch is booted.

My issue is that the service can run correctly for 12 hours...and then just suddenly stop. The amount of time appears to be non-deterministic, as sometimes it will stop after 40 minutes. I suspect it's being killed by Android, but in this case I would like it to restart. I have included `return START_STICKY` in my service and this should minimise the chance of it being killed.

In some solutions, I have seen `onDestroy()` overridden and a refresh broadcast being sent to the service. While this appears to work, the `onDestroy()` function is being called every time the `Handler` completes one piece of work. This leads to the service restarting every three minutes, rather than when the application is actually killed by Android.

I have also looked at the intent actions to see whether my service could be called at regular intervals. However, aside from `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`, all the useful ones cannot be registered in the Manifest file. Since the service will not be running, `registerReceiver()` would serve little purpose.

**Does anybody know of a technique to either a) guarantee a service will not be killed by Android; or b) guarantee that a service will always be restarted after it has been killed.** Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I've even started considering writing a Cron job on the device and setting it to execute my app every three minutes! I've also looked at the `AlarmManager` class, but I fear it is as likely to be killed if running for long periods.

Please find my code below: (AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.study">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">

        <receiver android:name="com.example.study.MyServiceManager" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.study.RestartAction" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.study.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name="com.example.study.RecordService"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

RecordService.java

```
package com.example.study;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.KeyguardManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.location.Location;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.google.android.gms.location.*;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class RecordService extends IntentService {

    private static Context context;
    private final static int INTERVAL = 1000 * 5; // 1 minutes
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Location myLocation;

    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

    SensorManager sensorManager;
    SensorManager gyroSensorManager;
    SensorManager compassSensorManager;
    SensorEventListener sensorEventListener;
    float[] accValues;
    float[] gyroValues;
    float[] compassValues;

    Runnable handlerTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                recordData();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            handler.postDelayed(handlerTask, INTERVAL);
        }
    };

    public RecordService() {
        super("RecordService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        handlerTask.run();
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void recordData() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MainActivity.getAppContext());

        boolean fineLocationGranted = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        boolean coarseLocationGranted = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

        boolean isLocationEnabled = isLocationEnabled(this);

        if(fineLocationGranted && coarseLocationGranted && isLocationEnabled) {

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long timeWaiting = 0L;

            mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Location location) {

                            if (location != null) {
                                myLocation = location;
                            } else {
                                System.out.print("");
                            }
                        }
                    });

            do {
                timeWaiting = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            } while (myLocation == null && timeWaiting < 200);

        }

        List<PackageInfo> packages = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
        KeyguardManager kg = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        boolean isLocked = kg.isDeviceSecure();

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        gyroSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        compassSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
                if(sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
                    accValues = sensorEvent.values;
                } else if(sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE){
                    gyroValues = sensorEvent.values;
                } else if(sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION) {
                    compassValues = sensorEvent.values;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {}
        };

        try {
            sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            gyroSensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            compassSensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        } catch(SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        long startTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long timeWaiting2 = 0L;

        do {
            timeWaiting2 = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime2;
        } while((accValues == null || gyroValues == null || compassValues == null) && timeWaiting2 < 200);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("G" + (isLocationEnabled ? 1 : 0));
        builder.append(" L" + (isLocked ? 1 : 0));

        if(accValues != null && gyroValues != null && compassValues != null) {
            builder.append(" ACX" + accValues[0]);
            builder.append(" ACY" + accValues[1]);
            builder.append(" ACZ" + accValues[2]);
            builder.append(" GYX" + gyroValues[0]);
            builder.append(" GYY" + gyroValues[1]);
            builder.append(" GYZ" + gyroValues[2]);
            builder.append(" CMX" + gyroValues[0]);
            builder.append(" CMY" + gyroValues[1]);
            builder.append(" CMZ" + gyroValues[2]);
        }

        if(myLocation != null) {
            builder.append(" LT" + myLocation.getLatitude());
            builder.append(" LN" + myLocation.getLongitude());
        }
        builder.append("\n");

        for(PackageInfo info: packages) {
            int lastDot = info.packageName.lastIndexOf('.');
            builder.append(info.packageName + "\n");
            if(info.requestedPermissions != null) {
                for (String rqprm : info.requestedPermissions) {
                    int dot = rqprm.lastIndexOf('.');
                    builder.append(rqprm.substring(dot != -1 ? dot + 1 : 0) + " ");
                }
                builder.append("\n");

                for (int permflag : info.requestedPermissionsFlags) {
                    builder.append("" + permflag + " ");
                }
                builder.append("\n");
            }
        }

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss");
        String currentDateString = sdf.format(new Date());
        File log = new File("/sdcard/Recordings/" + currentDateString);

        try {
            if (!log.exists()) {
                log.createNewFile();
            }
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(log, true));
            writer.append(builder.toString());
            writer.newLine();
            writer.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static boolean isLocationEnabled(Context context) {
        int locationMode = 0;
        String locationProviders;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
            try {
                locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);

            } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            return locationMode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF;

        } else {
            locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
            return !TextUtils.isEmpty(locationProviders);
        }
    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.study;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView mTextView;
    private static Context context;
    private static MainActivity activity;
    Intent serviceIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MainActivity.context = getApplicationContext();
        activity = this;

        serviceIntent = new Intent(this, RecordService.class);
        startForegroundService(serviceIntent)
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MainActivity.context;
    }

    public static MainActivity getActivity() {
        return activity;
    }

}
```

MyServiceManager.java

```
package com.example.study;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;

public class MyServiceManager extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: a service that always runs? a very bad idea.

Comment: use a foreground service instead

Comment: I think your problem is because of IntentService. Every time it finishes a task, it's destroyed. Then a better option could be working with a Service instead. And in onStartCommand you should return Service.START_STICKY